# How to store the contents of a folder/file to a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, path, face-api

I was playing around with the face-api when I ran into what feels like a simple issue: How do I declare a variable as equal to the contents of a local file?

I understand how to navigate a folder for the intended content when doing something such as setting the contents of say an image or script tag in HTML. However, I cant quite discern how to best do this in JavaScript.

- For example, lets say I have a folder titled "Images" which contains a file called "beach.jpeg". If I wanted to access the content of said jpeg for future use via something like the face-api how would I make the connection between my file and my JavaScript?

Would it look like the following:

```
const beachImage = Images/beach.jpeg
```

I feel like that formatting is missing something to discern that I am intending to access local files as opposed to something else. Thanks for any input! :)

Edit: I forgot to specify that I am running this in a browser and not using node.js. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Are you doing this on the server with node.js, or in a browser?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying in the original iteration of the post. I am running this in a browser.

Comment: In a browser you have to go through the file dialog to select files, you can't open them directly by name.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you running nodejs. you can read contents of a local image this way

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const beachImage = readFileSync('Images/beach.jpeg', 'binary'); // put the encoding you need
```

you might also gonna need a [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) to build correct path to a file

Edit for html approach. HTML with JS is about triggering and [catching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event#examples).
Here's an example that has [input tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) for letting a user choose an image. It displays chosen image. And you can do something with that image in the **action** function.

```html
<img id="image" src="" width="100" height="100">
<input id="input" name="photo" type="file" accept="image/*">
<button id="action-trigger">Trigger Action</button>

<script>
    window.onload = attachEventHandlers;

    function attachEventHandlers() {
        document.getElementById("input").onchange = handleUploadedImage;
        document.getElementById("action-trigger").onclick = action;
    }
  
    function handleUploadedImage(event) {
        const src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        document.getElementById('image').src = src;
    }

    function action() {
        const image = document.getElementById('image');
        if (image.src) {
            // do something with image.src
            // const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(input) // make sure you imported face-api.js
        } else {
            alert('Please upload an image first');
        }
    }
  
</script>
```

Comment: This was really insightful, thank you!